# Unexpected string whilst trying to load one element into another

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I'm trying to `.load()` the `#main-content` div from a particular `url` into my `#pane-other-topics` element, but I'm getting an `"Unexpected String Error"` I can't hunt down.

Can anyone help me solve this little bug?

Code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $("a.bbp-topic-permalink").live('click',function() {
            url = $(this).attr('href') . " #main-content";
            $('#other-topics-pane').load( url );
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: Here's the "loading page fragments" docs from jQuery I based this off of: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: you have `. " #main-content"`, you want `+ " #main-content"` the period is not a concatenation operator in javascript plus sign is. Use a lint program to validate your syntax [javascriptlint](http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php)

Comment: duh! thanks for the assist. Stupid php bad habits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:-

```
 url = $(this).attr('href') + " #main-content";
```

instead of

```
 url = $(this).attr('href') . " #main-content";
```

Answer (score 3):

To concatenate strings in JS, use a `+` not a `.`

```
url = $(this).attr('href') + " #main-content";
```